# Maximal distance between points on a line

Tags: absolute-value

Two points A and B are on different sides of a line.  Find a point Y on the line such that the absolute value of the difference from Y to A and Y to B is maximal.

My thoughts are as follows.  Let's say that point Y is on a line but is not collinear with A and B.  Then I could draw a triangle by joining the 3 points.  For this triangle, segment AB is less than the sum of AY and BY.  Then AB is greater than the absolute value of (YA-YB).  How can I prove that this difference is maximal?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find the function that yields the difference in the distances from $A$ to $Y$ and $B$ to $Y$ using the distance formula. This function will be of one variable since we know $A$, $B$, and the equation for the line. Then find the minimum or maximum of this function since we're looking for the greatest absolute value.

Answer (score -3):

(0,0) because that would make both lines the maximum size they could be

Comment: What if the line does not pass through $(0,0)$?

Comment: And even if it does, the two points A and B could be anywhere.  If (0,0) is the correct point for one value of A and B, just move them over to the right and now (0,0) is no longer correct.